# Java Applet Windows size in Eclipse

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to set the size of an Applet Window to 500 by 500, but I couldn't be able to achieve that.
Here is my code,

```
  public void init() { 
    // Start Screen Color 
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));

    width=getSize().width;
    height=getSize().height;

    running=false;
    repaint();
    offscreenImage = createImage(width,height);
    offscreenGraphics = offscreenImage.getGraphics();
    addKeyListener(this);    
    addFocusListener(this);

    waitingForSpace=false;

    repaint();
  }
```

When I pressed CTRL+F11 in Eclipse I get the output Window with size 200 by 200, Why I try to run the program like 5 to 10 times, sometimes the window returns with the 500 by 500 size while some time the window size is 200 by 200.

I do not understand why the size of the window i changing since I am not changing any code at all.
I want the size to remain at 500 by 500

Comment: I'm surprised your applet has ever appeared with a size of 500×500.  The size of an applet is controlled by the HTML elements in the web page (<applet>, <object>, etc.);  as far as I know, code cannot change it.

Comment: @VGR  You are correct about the applet size being set by the HTML.  Unfortunately many IDEs seem to encourage naive users into doing silly things (like attempting to set it in code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set size of applet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365183/how-to-set-size-of-applet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use eclipse, you can change applet size from the "run configuration" Java Applet->Parameters". I think that's the problem, because the default value of java applet size in eclipse is 200*200.

Hope it will helpful:
[a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759499/changing-the-size-for-my-applet-also-in-eclipse-run-as-applet)

Comment: Hello, there is no option of Parameters in Java Applet , there are no options at all

Comment: @Xufyan On the left of run configurations, double click "Java Applet" and you will see a tab "Parameters". Then you can run with the configuration you have created.

Answer (score 1):

try this inside the paint method for example

```
this.setSize(300, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the Applet Window, without looking for the eclipse .html is to choose "Run Configurations" in the "Run, '>' icon options " in the eclipse panel.  In the configurations choose "Parameters" and set the size of the applet in the two boxes available for 'height' and 'length.'  You may leave the box 'name' unfilled.

Comment: same in IntelliJ