# How do I change the size of my applet on JGrasp?

Tags: jgrasp

I wanted to know how I could change the size of the applet.I did it once back when I installed JGrasp but when I had to reinstall it due to a factory reset to my computer, I think it defaulted back to a bigger size, and I have not remembered/found any tutorial helping me do so.... Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set size of applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365183/how-to-set-size-of-applet)

Answer (score 0):

"Settings" > "Compiler Settings" > "Workspace" (or project)
Select language "Java" if not already selected.
Go to "HTML" tab.
Copy text, uncheck default box, paste text back in, change height and width.